# iOS alert "UI canceled by system"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview, ios9

Application display alert with text:"UI canceled by system" when press on the home button.

Have you any information what it mean? Or why it displayed?

[image]

Comment: you have localized "Warning" title and not localized text, so as for me, it's not the system message, you should look it in your code

Comment: when did get this alert. on clicking which part of UI.

Comment: This can be an error if you are using TouchID and if the system canceled the fingerprint dialog. Could happen if you lock the screen when the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a programming error in your code:
second local auth started before the first one was completed by the user.